# extra margin between DIVs

Tags: html, css

On [this website](https://staging.whitewreath.com/), there is a gap between `#container_head` & `#container_page`:

Can you see what is causing this gap? I can't. I tried creating a jsfiddle, but I thought showing you the live site would be quicker.

[image]

Comment: Your header id masthead has margin-bottom of 4.236em..remove that and you are done.

Comment: Simple, use #masthead{margin-bottom:0px} in style.css or necessary use !important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a margin-bottom for the header section, in the .site-header class. Remove it and it works fine

Comment: Because you are first, I'll pick your answer Mohith.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `#container_head` where `header#masthead` that has `margin-bottom: 4.236em`.

It's applied in CSS rule:

```
.home.blog .site-header, .home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header, .home.post-type-archive-product .site-header, .no-wc-breadcrumb .site-header {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The header has a bottom margin set in here:

```
.home.blog .site-header, .home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header, .home.post-type-archive-product .site-header, .no-wc-breadcrumb .site-header {
  margin-bottom: 4.236em;
}
```

Fix it by setting the following css (note below):

```
.home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I would be careful if you would set the `margin-bottom` to the whole declaration in the first place. Use the second way I provided. Otherwise it might have unwanted effects in other pages of your site.

Answer (score 1):

In your style there is margin-bottom issue as fix it

```
.home.blog .site-header, .home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header, .home.post-type-archive-product .site-header, .no-wc-breadcrumb .site-header{
 margin:0px !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding is coming from an internal div inside header with id=masthead. Please refer to the screen grab for details.[image]

once you remove it, your issue will be resolved.